# Wordpress submenu with submenu disappears upon hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, submenu

TEST URL: http://foundationpress.nick.devel.believe-it.nl/

On the first menu item I have a sub-menu containing another sub-menu, I can hover untill the last item of the 2nd sub-menu but I can't ever seem to reach the last item of the first sub-menu. I've been trying to resolve this problem for quite a while but I can't seem to find the solution, it seems to be within the CSS.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bring the menu to the front. Its hiding behind the text below, causing the hover effect to vanish and the cursor now hovers over the text.
Also, the hover effect in CSS is supposed to vanish when there is no more hover. For that slightly position the last submenu over the next last sub menu (Even about by a pixel will do).

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I've been trying to achieve this but I'm having trouble getting the last submenu selected properly. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There's some problem with your script. You can check it yourself. Hover over the cases and remove the cursor. Then come back and you find both cases and introduction gone. Maybe fixing that helps.

Comment: Fixed that problem, sadly it didn't fix the existing problem. I've tried to just always make the subsubmenu visible since that's no problem design wise but that only seems to screw up the CSS even more.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by this line in your js **$(this).children('a').removeClass('active-has-dropdown');** When the element loses hover, the second submenu is removed, so the introduction goes back up. But your cursor has gone below the position of introduction, so it vanishes. Try attaching the hover off handle to only the submenu not to subsubmenu and see if it worked.

Comment: I don't understand how that code can cause a problem, I've commented all of that cause it was my first guess to what was causing the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry. Didn't see those comments. So how exactly are you now creating the menu? Are you using some script or plain CSS?

Comment: It's standard Wordpress code with the Foundationpress theme which is creating the menu so I'm not completely sure but it seems to be done purely by CSS.

Comment: Sorry I won't be able to help right now. app.css is too big for me to read right now and app.js is not readable. I will try to help as soon as possible

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the suggestions so far!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#menu-main li, #menu-main li a {
    font-family: Asap;
    color: #00549a;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. I still can't seem to move my mouse past the "Mogelijkheden" item without the menu disappearing.